# Where does the unhandled SQLException I get comes from?

Tags: c#, image, exception, sql-server-express

I had this code;

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn;
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "server=.\\sqlexpress;database=Blue;trusted_connection=true";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Image from ImageParts where ImageName=" + listBox1.SelectedIndex, cnn);
        byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        cnn.Close();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

I have stored the `ImageName` in the `listBox1.Items`

Then, the error comes.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'c1.jpg' to data
>   type int.

What could be the problem? As I am new to C#, I am not familiar with those errors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `ImageName` field in your database is of datatype `int`, and you're passing a `string` to it (`varchar`).

Verify and correct the datatype of `ImageName` in your database.

Comment: I agree with Shark, the issue here is datatype mismatch

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the ImageName column in your database is a string type and not an int type. You are passing the index not the name of the image to your SqlCommand. And if this is the case don't forget to use the single quote around your string.

```
string nameImg = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Image from ImageParts where ImageName = '" + nameImg + "'");
```

Here I suppose that your listbox is filled with string names of your images

Answer (score 0):

Along with what Steve said you also should wrap your code in a try catch block break on the SQL command and see what the value is that is being sent to the server. get the command.CommandText.ToString() in you immediate window or through a watch, copy that value and  try and run it in SSMS parse it and see what happens and adjust your string accordingly. That way from now on you can see why it is failing and also handel errors accordingly in your program when things do fail.